# Have a user create files with 777 permission in linux

Tags: linux, bash, permissions

I have an application. The processes for the application have cacheusr as user. When I create files in the application I get the following ownership and permission:

```
aless80> ls -FGlAhpa test.xml
-rwxrw-r-- 1 cacheusr 1.6K Oct 19 16:41 test.xml
```

My question is: how to make sure the created files have permission 777 by default? I just added aless80 to the cacheusr group, but that does not help.

```
aless80> groups aless80
aless80 : aless80 adm cdrom sudo dip plugdev staff lpadmin sambashare cacheusr vboxusers

aless80> id aless80
uid=1000(aless80) gid=1000(aless80) groups=1000(aless80),4(adm),24(cdrom),27(sudo),30(dip),46(plugdev),50(staff),108(lpadmin),110(sambashare),1001(cacheusr),999(vboxusers)

aless80> groups cacheusr
cacheusr : cacheusr root

aless80> id cacheusr
uid=1001(cacheusr) gid=1001(cacheusr) groups=1001(cacheusr),0(root)
```

Comment: using `umask` ?

Answer (score 0):

you can control the permissions of newly created files with the `umask` command:

```
$ umask u+rwx,g+rwx,o+rwx
$ touch foo; mkdir bar
$ ls -ld foo bar
-rw-rw-rw- 1 user user    0 Oct 20 00:00 foo
drwxrwxrwx 2 user user 1024 Oct 20 00:00 bar
$
```

Comment: This does not work. I get -rwxr-xr-x permissions for files created by the process owned by cacheusr. 
The umask command cannot grant extra permissions.